# Is it possible to upload more than one file to Amazon S3 in single request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We are fetching binary blobs (PDF, JPG) from sql server and adding the object to Amazon S3 using `AWSSDK.S3 (.net) v3.7.2.2`.

Currently the process is adding the binary objects to Amazon S3 sequentially (one by one).

Is there any way/api to add more than one objects to Amazon S3 in a single request as this can improve the performance.

While adding the binary objects we have to pass metadata (Binary object properties like width, height, extension etc..) as well.

Comment: Upload in parallel. I have a script that uploads 20 files in parallel to push React websites to S3.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to upload/download multiple objects in one request.

However, Amazon S3 is highly scalable, so you can send multiple requests in parallel. This will also take more advantage of your available bandwidth due to the overhead of file transfer protocols.

Comment: Working in parallel is fine, but I was hoping to find a way to cut down on the costs of making many requests. I have many files, which in aggregate is a modest amount of storage... but it's millions of files, which are batch-updated daily (something I'm hoping to push up to multiple times daily). The PUT request costs overshadow the storage cost by a long mile, though.

Comment: @sytech PUT costs $0.005 per 1000 files so, yes, if you are uploading a large quantity of files then it can become a significant cost. You might consider **sending data to an Amazon Kinesis Firehose stream** and Kinesis can then batch the data into a smaller number of files (based on file size or by storing data over a given time period such as every 5 minutes). This all depends on **how you intend to use the files** in later processing. Feel free to create a new Question with details of your use-case.